# Filter sqlalchemy table update with Marshmallow schema

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm developing an api in Flask, using Marshmallow for serialization/deserialization/validation and SQLAlchemy as my ORM.

In my update functions I would like to restrict the fields that can be updated e.g. I don't want users to be able to change their email at the moment.

To achieve this I have set up a schema (UserSchema) with its fields restricted by a tuple (UserSchemaTypes.UPDATE_FIELDS).The tuple does not include email.

The problem I am having is that email is a required field for User rows in my database.

So when I create a User model object using the schema (users_schema.load(user_json) ) an illegal object is added to the sqlalchemy session.

```
#schema to validate the posted fields against  
users_schema = UserSchema(only=UserSchemaTypes.UPDATE_FIELDS)
#attempt to deserialize the posted json to a User model object using the schema
user_data = users_schema.load(user_json)
if not user_data.errors:#update data passed validation
   user_update_obj = user_data.data 
   User.update(user_id,vars(user_update_obj))
```

In my update function itself I then have to remove this illegal object from the session via db.session.expunge_all() as if I do not I receive an OperationalError.

```
@staticmethod    
def update(p_id,data):
    db.session.expunge_all()#hack I want to remove
    user = User.query.get(p_id)
    for k, v in data.iteritems():
        setattr(user, k, v)
    db.session.commit()
```

OperationalError received when db.session.expunge_all() is removed:

```
OperationalError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider        
using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) 
(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1048, &quot;Column 'email' cannot be   null&quot;) [SQL: u'INSERT INTO user (email, password, active, phone, current_login_at, last_login_at, current_login_ip, last_login_ip, login_count) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: (None, None, 1, '0444', None, None, None, None, None)]
```

Is there a better/cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Steven Loria https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-sqlalchemy/issues/33#issuecomment-147008000

Here are a couple different approaches you could take:

Option 1: Field parameter

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, pre_load

class BaseSchema(Schema):
    @pre_load
    def check_update_fields(self, data)
        non_update_fields = set([
            fname, fobj for fname, obj in self.fields
            if fobj.metadata.get('can_update') is False
        ])
        return {
            key: value for key, value in data.items()
            if key not in non_update_fields
        }

class UserSchema(BaseSchema):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Str(can_update=False)
```

Option 2: class Meta option

```
from marshmallow import Schema, SchemaOpts, fields, pre_load
class BaseSchemaOpts(SchemaOpts):
    def __init__(self, meta):
        super().__init__(meta)
        self.update_fields = getattr(meta, 'update_fields', set())

class BaseSchema(Schema):
    OPTIONS_CLASS = BaseSchemaOpts

    email = fields.Str(can_update=False)

    @pre_load
    def check_update_fields(self, data)
        non_update_fields = set(self.fields) - set(self.opts.update_fields)
        return {
            key: value for key, value in data.items()
            if key not in non_update_fields
        }

class UserSchema(BaseSchema):

    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Str()

    class Meta:
        update_fields = ('name', )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database does not match your model.

You should sync the database because you changed something about your model (email null to not null).  Either remove the table and resync the database, or use a migration tool to modify the table to match your model.